# Is there a library to group list of entities by several attributes

Tags: java, grouping, aggregate

Assume there's a structure `Pay` with attributes: `category`, `location`, `department`, `sum`.
Having a collection of such entities I want to group it by `category` and `location` to get such a structure:
`category - location - collection of Pays`

There's a Guava Multimaps.index() function, but it works only for one-level grouping. And I need 2+.

Doesn't matter what type this structure will have - some `Map<Map<Map>>` implementation or smth else.

I just don't want to write multi-iteration code. Hope there's a library for such operation. Do you know one?

P. S. Great if works on Java 7.

Comment: Take a look at [`Guava's Multimap`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap)

Comment: @dguay, there's a Guava Multimaps.index() function, but it works only for one-level grouping. And I need 2+.